# SQL Select on condition and calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've really hit a brick wall here and I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I have an SQL database that looks like this:

```
Course              Extension Max   Extension 1 Extension 1 Used    Extension 2 Extension 2 Used
Excel Introduction        24             12           TRUE              12         FALSE
Word Introduction         24             12           TRUE              12         TRUE
```

So with the above data, what I want to calculate is the Remaining Extension days, so for the first row the remaining days would be 12, as we've one block of 12 days and another 12 day block remains.

The second column would show a remaining day of zero/0 as both 12 day blocks have been used.

If both values are FALSE, then it should just display the Extension Max in days in a column as the extension hasn't been used yet.

How can I create a new column or just a variable to calculate and display the remaining days?

Any help would be appreciated, as always, thank you.

Comment: And what if both are "false"?

Comment: Hi Gordon, I've edited the post to answer that. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would seem to want something like this:

```
select t.*,
       ((case when Extension1Used = 'false' then Extension1 else 0 end) +
        (case when Extension2Used = 'false' then Extension2 else 0 end)
       ) as remaining_extension_days
from t;
```

Or, you could phrase this as:

```
select t.*,
       (case when Extension1Used = 'false' and Extension2Used = 'false' 
             then ExtensionMax
             when Extension1Used = 'false'
             then Extension1
             when Extension2Used = 'false'
             then Extension2
             else 0
        end) as remaining_extension_days
from t;
```

The first form is simpler, and should work if the maximum extension is the sum of the individual extensions.

Comment: Thank you Gordon, I've had a quick look and I think this is what I'm after.